# itemLabel="#{client2.nomClient}": Property 'nomClient' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i would be retrieve the select value of selectOneMenu , but when i execute the programme this exeception appear :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - /pages/T.xhtml @59,33 itemLabel="#{client2.nomClient}": Property 'nomClient' not found on type java.lang.String
```

this is my view:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{ticketBean.maValeur}" 
                            style="width:210px; height:20px; font-size:10px; font-weight:1px;"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="REQUIRED">
                            <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Select Client"  itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems  value="#{ticketBean.getMesElementsTest()}" var="client2" itemLabel="#{client2.nomClient}" itemValue="#{client2.nomClient}"
                                style="font-size:10px;">
                            </f:selectItems>
```

this is my class client :

```
package com.model;

public class Client {
    private int idClient;
    private String nomClient;
    private String adresseClient;
    private String telephoneClient;
    private String mailClient;

// GETTERS && SETTERS 
}
```

this is my fonction getMesElementsTest :

```
 private static Map<String, Object> mesElementsTest;
    private static ClientDaoImp clientDaoImp= new ClientDaoImp();   
    public static Map<String, Object> getMesElementsTest() {
        mesElementsClient = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Client> clientlist = clientDaoImp.getAllClients();
        Iterator<Client> i = clientlist.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Client client=i.next();
            mesElementsClient.put(client.getNomClient(),client.getNomClient());

        }    
        return mesElementsClient;
    }
```

Comment: Please post evidence that `#{client2}` isn't an instance of `java.lang.String`. You didn't disprove the exception message anywhere in the question.

Comment: Please post the code of `client2` class. I think ther's no `nomClient` atribute.

Comment: @ColdHack the client2 it's not class it's name of var i changed the class client but not work and the execption messege still

Comment: Can you post the signature of `getMesElementsTest` method?

Comment: @ColdHack  this is the signature : private static Map<String, Object> mesElementsTest

Comment: @ColdHack i would be retrieve the select value of this selectItem for to adding in my  dataBAse i stil blocked :(

Comment: The method is private? How can you access this on jsf page? This is strange, and  as i know, using maps, you can only take the or the key (a String) or the value (the Object). How do you fill you map?

Comment: @ColdHack i add the the definition of my fonction at the top

Comment: Ok. You can use only the list. You dont need to put it on a Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only the `List`, and have something like this:

```
...
public static List<Client> getMesElementsTest() {
        return clientDaoImp.getAllClients();    
        } 
...
```

on page:

```
...    
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{ticketBean.maValeur}" style="..." required="true" requiredMessage="...">
       <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Select Client"  itemValue=""/>
       <f:selectItems  value="#{ticketBean.getMesElementsTest()}" var="client2" itemLabel="#{client2.nomClient}" itemValue="#{client2.nomClient}" style="...">
    </f:selectItems>
...
```

And, this form it's more efficient, beacause you dont need fill other data-structure.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thk you very match for your help but my problems it not in function it in var="Client2" the view not found in attribut on the type  java.lang.String

Comment: If the problem persists, please unmark the question as answered, and let's try again solve the real problem. Have tried use as my example on the answer?